# New Flutter projects results in a blank project

Tags: flutter

This type of steps follws for flutter setup :

```
 1)download latest version of v1.7.8+hotfix.4 this below link
    https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases
    2)my flutter store in this url : C:\src
    3)set enviroment variable C:\src\flutter\bin
    4)Android studio download  and install.
    5)install plugin flutter & dart...in android studio...than after restart IDE.
    6) than after i have to start a new flutter project
    -flutter_demo  (project name) 
    -C:\src\flutter (SDK path)
    -C:\src\flutter_project (project location)

my issue is this when i have to create new flutter project only create blank folder in this location [[C:\src\flutter_project]] no any other process.
what is my issue??? i need to help???
```

---

this step follow another PC in window 7

### --work properly

-but in my pc not working.

### -my pc os is also window 7

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project from the [command line](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal#create-app) on your own pc?

Comment: Paste the output of `flutter doctor`. Also paste the screenshot of the files and folders created in the project if any.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the same problem  about creating flutter blank project. In my case, I check the installation steps and all are correct.

The answer is in *User Environment Variable Path*, there is also old `flutter/bin` path that I had tested before.

I deleted the old flutter bin path and also in *System Environment Variable Path*. Then, I can create flutter project and run **futter doctor** successfully.